# .Net Persisting Large Lists and Keeping data up to date in near realtime

Tags: c#, .net, sql, wpf, wcf

Ok, hold on because there's a lot of layers to this and although it might take a bit to read though all this, I think the answer(s) we all come up with will be tremendously useful for the community at large.With that said, let me setup the problem:

I have a C# .Net desktop application (Windows Forms but it could just as easily be WPF I would think) that is a sales order entry and management system. The problem I'm running into is that one of the most important lists of data that I need to use in the application is rather big (about 15k records, and growing) and is contantly changing and I'd like to keep the list in memory in-sync with the database, while not polling the database every 2 seconds or whatever. The application is also not single-instance so all these lists the application needs are brought into memory from the database and persisted once per instance.

Ok, now that you can see the dilema, let's see if we can come up with a solution.

My thoughts:

If we are able to use .NET 4.0 (which I can) I think the answer to the keeping only one set of data in memory is the use of memory mapped files.  While it seems at face value a homerun, it is much more complex to manage and might be overkill. Thoughts?

For keeping the data loads from the database to a minimum I was thinking of something like persisting the various lists to XML text files on the user's PC in some special folder, and then one final XML file for keeping track of the XML files and their dates. On application startup a single call to the DB is executed getting the list of tables/lists and the "last updated date" for each. For each XML file that has the same last updated date, I can load from the XML file rather then query the database.  As for lists that are out of date I could query for the changes since the date I have and then load the XML file and then commit the changes. This way, more then likely the only changes I'll have to wait on are the changes from the more frequently updated lists, not all the tables/lists. Ok, I'll admit I'm not the best at explaining things but I think you should be able to visualize it.

As for the keeping things up to date in real time I was thinking about having insert and update triggers (no deletes will occur) that call SPs that then, and this is where I'm a bit fuzzy, somehow pass the inserted/updated info to a WCF service which the applications have subscribed to and the updates are pushed to the clients though WCF callbacks. Now I think this should all work but, for example wouldn't this cause 3 instances of the app be tring to update the same change in memory at the same time? Is the WCF service able to send the updates to only one instance per client PC; can it differenciate?

Thanks in advance for any and all thoughts, opinions, and input on this.  I will reserve "awarding" an answer for at least 48 hours as I would like to give everyone a chance to throw their 2 cents in and make this thread a little more useful for the future...

Comment: cache it in your wcf service layer?

Comment: Please tell me "15k" and "ComboBox" are separate things.

Comment: You should be able to use WCF's net-tcp binding to have the server push out change notifications to the connected clients about updates to the tables, which would solve your polling problem at least. Different instances of the app should have their own in-memory copy of the data and their own WCF connection, so it should be alright until you try and persist it.

Comment: @Tridus - I will look into what you are saying, but assuming I have several lists, that 15k one being the biggest, but others are shorter but have mor columns. Won't having 3-4 instances each with their own set easily congest a PC with only 2 or 3 GB of memory when the user also has Outlook and a few other things open?

Comment: @Wonko the Sane - Think of it more as an auto-complete rather than a DropDownList. The user types in the majority of the name or the id and the code-behind does the matching up, if built-in autocomplete logic didn't find a match... Also, remember the data binding is virtualized.

Comment: @user418754 Unless these columns contain things like byte arrays (binary files) or other really big things, probably not. Numbers and dates don't take much space, and once its loaded it should be alright. :) In my experience .net can handle a data set like that in memory, it's when you try to display it all at once that things get ugly. Without seeing more details I can't say for 100% certain, but IMHO you will be alright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way, and probably the best way, to accomplish this is through journalling.

To implement this, associate a journal table with a database table that you need to keep updated on each client.  This table's primary key is a timestamp.  Whenever any client updates or inserts a row in (say) the customer table, it also adds a row to the journal table indicating the primary key of the customer that's been added or updated.

Every client can then find the list of changes by querying the journal table, finding all rows where the primary key is greater than or equal to the timestamp of the client's last query (which the client tracks).  A simple join to the customer table gets all of the new and updated rows.  The client then merges these rows into its local copy of the customer table.

You say that you don't want to hit the database every 2 seconds or whatever.  Three thoughts about that.

First, it should be simple enough to prototype this and determine whether or not hitting the database every 2 seconds is actually a problem that you need to solve.

Second:  *every 2 seconds?*  That smells to me like a requirement driven by a belief in magic rather than by an actual business need.  And if it is driven by a business need, it makes me worry about much deeper problems, like:  assuming that it takes the user more than 2 seconds to perform a transaction involving a customer, what happens if the customer row changes during the transaction?

And finally:  even if you do ultimately need to implement a broadcast model, the starting point for the broadcast will be a work queue of items that need to be sent to clients.  Journalling's a good starting point for that.

Protip:  don't forget to implement the end-of-day process that purges old entries out of the journal tables.

Comment: Wouldn't taking the broadcast approach combined with the memory mapped files cause the least network utilization and the least memory usage on the client PCs? Also having the changes pushed live to the clients would allow more posibilities?   Overall though I agree with your journaling approach if the triggers firing off the broadcast approach fails somehow.

Answer (score 5):

I can't see the gain in keeping a database in memory.  The point of a database is to be a database.

**You are going have to reproduce multi-user database functionality in your application.**

This seems like a no win proposition.  Leave that to Microsoft.  Instead make an n-tier application that uses all the functionality of sql server.  Then when you have a working beta version look for parts of the application which are slow and move from there.

Comment: It is already working, I'm just trying to make it more efficient then it is today. I'm not trying to persist the database in the app's memory, just a List of Customer objects for example (int id, string name) for a combo box and other lookup needs.

Comment: You already have it working as an n-tier, but the drop downs are slow because they have to read a lot of stuff from the DB?

Comment: No, the drop downs are fast as I'm using controls that vitualize the data. It binds the items that are visible but sets the scrollbar to the amount it would be if it was full. Virtualized controls can handle millons of records before any noticable slowdown.

Comment: Virtualize the data sounds good.  So what exactly is the issue.  Are you worried about the data changing while a user is viewing the page?

Comment: Partly. More likely a customer is added to the system and assigned to a rep and then they're told over the phone or email maybe that it's in there and of course the rep expects the change to be made immediately. Likewise a data change on the customer...

Answer (score 1):

I have similar needs in my program, but my solution has been to build classes that load the database objects lazily (as they're needed) and even partially for some of the more important and larger items (just the primary key and name to begin with).  Then whenever the database item I'm looking at is either uninitialized (just PK and name) or still null, I go to the database and eagerly load that object and several other objects of its kind.

If you have a UI element with 15k items in it your program will be mostly unusable by a human (might as well not display anything at all and just keep it in a List).  You should consider using a search dialog or something similar instead.

Comment: I use controls that virtualize the lists so the entire list is never actually bound at one time... I am curently doing something like what you are, but I'm foced to check every so often for changes, and if all the clients are checking all the time, bad...

Comment: Then you should reconsider your application's design.  Can your users work with a subset of the data? (they'll be more efficient that way too)

Comment: Some users need it all, but most just get "their" customers. For example, if there are 15k total customers a given sales rep may only get their 250~300 assigned customers, whereas the execs will see all customers. Also, all users can view basic info and search for any customer.

Comment: About 75 active users with 15~20 more infrequent users.  My concern right now is the server and clinet PC hardware isn't too spiffy and until it gets upgraded I want to find the best way to do this possible.

Comment: How resilient is the system to handling out of date information and how often does a piece of data change during a session?

Comment: Data changes about every 5-10 minutes but users expect it to be immediately available without a app reload or logoff/logon. Currently if data changes when the user has something open it will not allow them to save saying, "Another user has submitted changes since you loaded the current xxxx. Please...". So it alerts them there was a change but I'd like it to change in the background unless it was a major key item that would completely invalidate the user's current course.